# Check variables with loop in Bash

Tags: bash, loops, variables

I built a script where you set variables in a specific file.

Now I wanted to script a check if all variables in the file are not empty/unset.

Here is a sample file:

```
#variables.tmp
export foo=1
export bar=
```

Here is my code where I try to find out if it is all set or not:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATHTOVARIABLES=/usr/local

#read variables
source $PATHTOVARIABLES/variables.tmp

#seperate comments from variables in file export.tmp
cat $PATHTOVARIABLES/variables.tmp | grep export > $PATHTOVARIABLES/export.tmp

#get variables in form "${var}"
sed -i "s/export /\"\$\{/g" $PATHTOVARIABLES/export.tmp
sed -i "s/=.*/\}\"/g" $PATHTOVARIABLES/export.tmp

#for-loop to read in variables
for i in `cat $PATHTOVARIABLES/export.tmp`
do

#check if variables are set or not
  if [ -z $i ]; then
    echo "Variable " $i " set"
  else
    echo " Variable not set"
  fi

done

rm $PATHTOVARIABLES/export.tmp
```

In return I get "Variable not set" whether the variable is set or not...

I used the `if` condition I found there: https://serverfault.com/questions/7503/how-to-determine-if-a-bash-variable-is-empty

Can you explain what is wrong with my code? I'm new to bash scripting so please be patient ;-)

Comment: Is it not working? What isn't working? Run your code through http://shellcheck.net and fix the problems it lists (see [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) to replace your for loop).

Comment: Have you double-checked *any* of your intermediate results? What's in `export.tmp` after your `sed`'s? What does `i` contain? *Why does everyone willing to help you have to figure this out individually?*

Comment: Are you *testing* scripts with a user that has *write* access to `/usr/local`? Really?

Comment: What version of `bash` are you using?

Comment: What I wanted to have was `if [ -z "${foo}" ]; then`. I thought this works because `i` contains the string `"${foo}"`. I will give DevSolar solution a try

Answer (score 1):

First, note that by definition the variables are set following the `source` command; `bar=` sets a variable to an empty string.

There's no need for `grep` or a temporary file; you can iterate
over the file in `bash` and check each variable as you read it from
the file. Use indirect parameter expansion to find the value of a parameter given its name as a string.

```
#!/bin/bash

PATHTOVARIABLES=/usr/local

#read variables
source $PATHTOVARIABLES/variables.tmp

# Get the name of each exported value
while IFS='= ' read tag name value; do
    [[ $tag == export ]] || continue
    # Indirect expansion: get the value of
    # the parameter whose name is $name
    value=${!name}
    if [[ -z $value ]]; then
        echo "$name has empty value"
    else
       echo "$name has value ${!name}"
    fi
done < "$PATHTOVARIABLES/variables.tmp"
```

There are a few special cases you might want to consider that you don't explicitly mention: a single `export` command can set the values of multiple variables, and an `export` command can export one or more names without actually setting a value for them.

Answer (score -1):

```
PATHTOVARIABLES=/usr/local
```

Requiring write access to a system directory is never a good idea. I took the liberty to redefine that to something in my home dir.

```
source $PATHTOVARIABLES/variables.tmp
```

At this point, `foo` is set to `1`, and `bar` is unset.

```
cat $PATHTOVARIABLES/variables.tmp | grep export > $PATHTOVARIABLES/export.tmp

#get variables in form "${var}"
sed -i "s/export /\"\$\{/g" $PATHTOVARIABLES/export.tmp
sed -i "s/=.*/\}\"/g" $PATHTOVARIABLES/export.tmp
```

At this point `export.tmp` contains:

```
"${foo}"
"${bar}"
```

Works as designed.

```
#for-loop to read in variables
for i in `cat $PATHTOVARIABLES/export.tmp`
do
```

At this point `i` contains the string `"${foo}"` (and, in the second loop, `"${bar}"`).

```
#check if variables are set or not
if [ -z $i ]; then
```

No, you're checking if the variable `i` is empty or not. It contains `"${foo}"`, which is not empty, and thus the condition is false, so...

```
echo " Variable not set"
```

Computers do exactly what you tell them, not what you *want* them to do. ;-)

I figured this out by adding the lines `echo $foo`, `echo $bar`, `cat $PATHTOVARIABLES/export.tmp`, and `echo $i` in the appropriate places, significantly narrowing down where your script stops meeting your expectations. You could have done this yourself, giving a much shorter question...

If you are looking for a way to check if the variable *named* in `i` is set,
**then the command you are looking for is `eval` (cautionary warning below).**

```
for i in `cat $PATHTOVARIABLES/export.tmp`
do
    eval "tmp=${i}"    # expands to tmp="${foo}" / tmp="${bar}" and gets evaluated

    if [[ -z $tmp ]]
    then
        echo "Variable ${i} is not set."
    else
        echo "Variable ${i} is set to ${tmp}."
    fi
done
```

---

**Caution:**

Using `eval` on external input is **potentially dangerous**. If an attacker has the ability to tinker with whatever your script is feeding to `eval` (in this case, the file `variables.tmp`), then he can make your script execute commands with the privileges of whatever user is executing the script (in your case, `root` -- which is why testing something as `root` is not a good idea).

I cannot see a way this could happen in your specific case, but I asked user chepner, who seems to disagree.

Comment: @chepner: And you know that how? And what do *you* think he *is* looking for?

Comment: Because you are only using it for indirect variable expansion, for which there is an operator in `bash`. The user apparently doesn't know enough about the variables he's defining to know what their names are, let alone whether the values are safe to pass to `eval`. I'm waiting to find out what version of `bash` he is using to suggest the best *safe* answer.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! 
I switched to my Homedir, but I tested it by user root, so I have write access.
What I wanted to have was `if [ -z "${foo}" ]; then`
I thought this works because `i` contains the string `"${foo}"`. Is there a solution so that it is checking the content of `i` instead of `i` itself.

//Edit
I will give your solution a try.

Comment: @chepner: Can you to show me an example line for `variables.tmp` that would be exploiting `eval` here, with the preprocessing as by the OP's script?

Comment: @chepner: my bash version is Version 4.3.30